# Is this Hadith on Mawlid a Hadith and authentic?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, uloom-al-hadith

> "I saw the Prophet ﷺ in my sleep, and told him about the practice of holding celebratory feasts on the day of his birth and he replied “If someone rejoices in us, we rejoice in him!"
>
> — Shaykh Abū Mūsā al-Zarhūnī (ra)

This has been suggested as proof of the Mawlid Al Nabi. Is this reliable and can we use what a Shaykh sees in a dream of Rasoolullah as evidence - as if you see him it is him as Shaytaan can't impersonate the Prophet.

Comment: Please provide a reference to who Abu Musa al-Zarhuni is (his _tarjamah_), and where he said so. This will be the first step prior to establishing whether the dreams of Abu Musa al-Zarhuni can be considered a source of _tashrī'_ in Islam.

Comment: The meaning of the hadith of seeing the prophet pbuh in dreams is discussed, as no one else then the sahaba would be able to recognize the Prophet pbuh if they saw him in a dream. And you posted the so called salat al-fatih without giving any link to the actual question. Also this certainly is not a hadith in the terms held by sunni Muslims (and I wonder if shi'a would consider it as such) as Abu Musa al-Zahruni doesn't belong to the sahaba nor tabi'yn nor any of the 3 first centuries.

Comment: If you are the original poster, just register one account and stick with it so you can edit your own posts. If you created multiple accounts by accident, you can merge them by following the instructions at https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts. Answers are for *answering the question*, not for making edits to other posts or flagging things for community/moderator attention.